# Add css class to the specified form validator message in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Is it possible to get form validator messages markup like this?

```
<ul class="error">
    <li>Error msg 1</li>
    <li class="custom">Error msg 2</li>
</ul>
```

With 'Error' and 'HtmlTag' form decorators I can only make like this:

```
<span class="custom">
  <ul class="error">
    <li>Error msg 1</li>
    <li>Error msg 2</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Here is my element code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'domain', array(
'label' => $this->getTranslator()->_('Your domain'),
'attribs' => array(
    'maxlength' => 200,
    'size' => 30
),
'validators' => array(),
'filters' => array(),
'required' => TRUE,
'decorators' => array('Errors',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'custom'))
    ),
));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element errors are by default rendered using `Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors` ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Decorator/Errors.php)) decorator and `Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors` ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/FormErrors.php)) view helper. The decorator has no support for custom attributes per error line.

To allow custom attributes per error, you would first need to extend/override the `Zend_Form_Decorator_Errors#render()` method to retrieve specific options of each error and feed it to `$view->formErrors($errors, $this->getOptions());`. You would then need to override the `Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors#formErrors()` to add the specific attributes to the `<li>` elements.